# Get all calls to a specified method plus it's argument list with Roslyn

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, roslyn

How can I extract all calls to CallApiAsync from **Roslyn** based on some sample code below. For example, in the code below, I'd be hoping to extract the following call

```
CallApiAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(x => x.GetResponse(new SomeRequestType()));
```

and be able to extract the generic args **ISomeApi, SomeResponseType** plus the lambda expression method invoked **GetResponse** with the argument **SomeRequestType**

```
public class ApiWrapper
{
    public delegate TResult ApiMethodAsync<T, TResult>(T api);

    public virtual SomeResponseType MakeSomeRequestToApi()
    {
        return CallApiAsync<ISomeApi, SomeResponseType>(x => x.GetResponse(new SomeRequestType()));
    }

    public virtual TResult CallApiAsync<T, TResult>(ApiMethodAsync<T, TResult> apiMethod) where TResult : new()
    {
       return new TResult();
    }
}

public interface ISomeApi
{
    SomeResponseType GetResponse(SomeRequestType request);
}

public class SomeResponseType { }
public class SomeRequestType { }
```